# How to display a list of QPushButton?

Tags: python, qt, list, pyside, qpushbutton

I am a qt noob and I am trying to build an application that needs to display the following:

- a list of e-mail (which I am displaying in column 1 of a grid layout
  with a QListWidget1 left list)
- a list of passwords (which I display in column 2 of grid layout in a QListWidget2 middle list)

Now, I would like to display a list of button (1 for every element of the list) which is supposed to copy the password in the QListWidget2.

Should I just loop in column 3 and add a push button for every row? Or is there a better way of doing this? Is there an object that could help me by laying out the buttons already in line with the elements of my list, so that I can connect them easily with the value of every entry in the list (for copying them later)?

My code is the following:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(311, 499)
    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 291, 371))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    # self.dockWidget = QtGui.QDockWidget(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    # self.dockWidget.setObjectName("dockWidget")
    # self.dockWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
    # self.dockWidgetContents.setObjectName("dockWidgetContents")
    # self.dockWidget.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents)
    # self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dockWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)


    self.leftList = QtGui.QListWidget(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.leftList, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.middleList = QtGui.QListWidget(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.middleList, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.rightList = QtGui.QListWidget(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rightList, 0, 2, 1, 1)

    self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(Dialog)
    self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 410, 231, 23))
    self.progressBar.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
    self.progressBar.setMaximum(30)
    self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 30)
    self.progressBar.setInvertedAppearance(False)
    self.progressBar.setTextDirection(QtGui.QProgressBar.TopToBottom)
    self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 413, 51, 16))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 440, 291, 51))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.line = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
    self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 390, 291, 20))
    self.line.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.HLine)
    self.line.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.line.setObjectName("line")

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.progressBar.setFormat(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "%vs", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "TimeOut", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Refresh", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: Do you really need a separate button for _every_ list item? Why not just have one button that copies the current/selected list item?

Comment: Hi, you are right. I wanted though, for the user to click only once. This would force the user to first select and entry, and then copy it.

You made me feel stupid tho, it was very obvious. I will look in the doc if there is an "autocopy" on click for widget items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a button for each item in the list, you can use [setItemWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget).

To get the buttons to align to the right, use a layout as in the demo script below:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)

    def addListItem(self, text):
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(text)
        self.list.addItem(item)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.list)
        button = QtGui.QToolButton(widget)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.list.setItemWidget(item, widget)
        button.clicked[()].connect(
            lambda: self.handleButtonClicked(item))

    def handleButtonClicked(self, item):
        print(item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    for label in 'red blue green yellow purple'.split():
        window.addListItem(label)
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will combine it with a contextual menu for every item in the list!